# How to model a relationship one to many which is kind of conditional

Tags: sqlite, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm a beginner in sql and data modelling. I'm going through Zed  Shaw's tuorial [SQL the hard way](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/). Beside completing the exercises I try to figure out some things on my own. Along the tutorial I'm asked to create a pet table. I want to connect the pets to a fur_color table to track the colour of the pet's fur.

My question is, that not all pets (like birds) have fur. I just want to save fur colur for pets with fur. It seems to me that there is some underlying condition (do the pet have fur).

My solution so far , based on the assumption that the relationship is a one to many relation (one pet can have one colour and one colour can have many pets): I created a new table fur_colour with the attributes id, id_pet and colour. I wonder if this is correct, because I store the colour each time for each record.

```
CREATE TABLE pet (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    breed TEXT,
    dead INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE fur_colour (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    pet_id INTEGER,
    colour TEXT
);
INSERT INTO pet (id, name, breed)
    VALUES  (1,"Santa's Little Helper", 'dog'),
            (2,'Snowball II', 'cat'),
            (3,'Canary M. Burs', 'bird');
INSERT INTO fur_colour (id, pet_id, colour)
    VALUES  (1, 1, 'brown'),
            (2, 2, 'black');
SELECT pet.name, fur_colour.colour FROM pet, fur_colour WHERE
    pet.id = fur_colour.pet_id;
```

Another solution is to create a table colour where all possible colours are stored and connect fur and colour with the table fur_colour, where I just store the colour_id and the pet_id. But so far I learned that this solution is to model many to many relationships.

```
CREATE TABLE pet (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
breed TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE fur_colours (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    colour TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE pet_colour (
    id_pet INTEGER,
    id_colour INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO pet (id, name, breed)
    VALUES  (1,"Santa's Little Helper", 'dog'),
            (2,'Snowball II', 'cat'),
            (3,'Canary M. Burs', 'bird');
INSERT INTO fur_colours (id, colour)
    VALUES  (1, 'grey'),
            (2, 'brown'),
            (3, 'white'),
            (4, 'black');

INSERT INTO pet_colour (id_pet, id_colour)
    VALUES  (1, 2),
            (2, 4);

SELECT pet.name, fur_colours.colour FROM pet, fur_colours, pet_colour WHERE
    pet.id = pet_colour.id_pet AND
    fur_colours.id = pet_colour.id_colour;
```

Is there a better way to model this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution represents colours using English names.  Names don't make good identifiers for colours - they require everything to be named, can be written in various ways (grey vs gray vs Gray vs GREY ... etc), assume a preferred language, and aren't efficient representations.  However, if you have a fixed list of values, and set up the right check constraints, this solution could work well enough.

Your second solution represents colours via surrogate numbers.  This could work if you have a limited list of acceptable colours.  Surrogate ids are more stable than names, and having a table of valid colours makes it easier to maintain (adding/removing colours require manipulating data instead of schema).  Again, be sure to set up the right constraints to ensure valid data - a unique constraint on the name, and a foreign key constrain to prevent invalid pet colours.

For a wider variety of colours, you could represent them as numbers in a given colour space.  For example, a 32-bit integer could represent RGB values: black = 0, red = 16711680, yellow = 16776960, white = 16777215.  These are easily convertible from/to hex.  If you want to name colours, then you could use a table like your fur_colours, but using the RGB value as identifier instead of a surrogate id.

In general, finding a good identifier for each entity is one of the hidden arts of database design.  One size don't fit all.  Natural keys are very valuable and should be included in a design, even if they're not used for primary key (but using them as such often makes a database easier to work with).  Sometimes keys are composite.  Often surrogate ids are necessary.  One could write an entire book about identity and representation.

Now, your table designs for fur_colour / pet_colour have an issue - neither enforce the cardinality of the relation!  If you make the pet_id the primary key (and drop the surrogate id in the case of fur_colour), that would enforce the requirement that a pet has only one colour.  It's the primary/unique constraint on the pet_id that makes it one-to-many (or the lack of it that makes it many-to-many), not whether your colours are represented via name or surrogate id.